# Is there a libc implementation contained in a single C file?

Tags: libc, vax

I'm looking for a libc implementation in a single C source file.

Previously, I tried decompiling musl's `libc.so` with Ghidra but the result contained too many errors. Even after manually fixing these errors the result is too far removed from the original source code for my needs.

I found [this](https://github.com/ferhatgec/flibc/blob/master/flibc.h) but I was hoping to find something more complete. For example, including some of the `math.h` functions and `printf`.

Then today I found a mention of the VAX/VMS C compiler in a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50266/2037637) which states:

> The VAX/VMS C compiler kept all the C runtime library headers in a single textual library file (similar to a unix archive), and used the string between the < and > as the key to index into the library. –
> Adrian McCarthy
> Feb 15, 2017 at 23:14

This might fit my needs, if the "textual library file" contains C source code.

So primarily I'm looking for a single-file libc.c implementation. But if someone has a link to this VAX/VMS C compiler archive file, I'd be interested in that too.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. _Why_ do you need a single `C` source file?

Comment: I want to analyze many (hundreds of) *syntactically different* but *semantically equivalent* variations of libc functions. I hoped to generate these variations with [Tigress[(https://tigress.wtf/), whose input must be a single C file.